# Bash - Correct number in indian Phone Number format

Tags: bash, tr

I have a csv 18th column has indian phone numbers.

```
+91 8889990098
+91 888999009
+91 88899900981
889990098
8889990098
+1 77799888999
+91 0189990098
+91 118999009
+91 44899900981
```

All i need correct Indian Mobile numbers from above numbers list (without +91 and without space)

---

This is how far i go >>

echo 'Phone: +91 01234 567890' | tr -d '+91' | tr -cd '[:digit:]' > a.txt |

Comment: Try to experiment with this one liner: cat XXX.CSV | cut -d';' -f18 | sed 's|+91[ ]*||g' | egrep '^[9876]{1}'     ... delimiter in CSV is in this example ";"

Comment: @HonzaP. Thanks a lot for quick reply...

It give me this reusult in 18th column

+1 77799888999
189990098
118999009
44899900981

Comment: @HonzaP. i guess i need codition if the command check . wether the number is 10 digit or not...

Comment: Just try to update your question please. The more precise question you ask the more precise answers you get ... Even my answer was general, just to put you somewhere on track to your desired result :-).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could go for solving this. One way could be a regular expression:

```
grep -Po "^(\+91[ ]*)?\K.*$" test.txt
```

input:

```
+91 8889990098
+91888999009
+91 88899900981
889990098
8889990098
+1 77799888999
+91 0189990098
+91 118999009
+91 44899900981
```

Output:

```
8889990098
888999009
88899900981
889990098
8889990098
+1 77799888999
0189990098
118999009
44899900981
```

To explain the command:

- -P enables perl regex (to have more options than default grep)
- -o only shows the matched things on the single line, instead of showing the whole line
- The block (+91)? makes the "+91" optional
- The block [ ]* makes any amount of spaces optional. It's inside the previous block to only match spaces when the +91 is present.
- The \K makes all the previous a "lookbehind" block. Basically it makes the previous stuff not match (we don't want to see that)
- .* matches anything else on the line. You could replace this with [0-9 +]+ for example if you also have lines with something else than phone numbers
- The ^ means beginning of the line and $ means end of the line.

Comment: IMHO, no need to use `cat` with `grep` in your command, `grep` can read file by itself.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I agree. But looking at the examples I felt like he was already piping output, therefore I chose to give an example where grep gets output from a pipe. Changed answer to reflect your comment anyway.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Most of the comments I cant see, am i missing something ?